# Pylint - Unable to import a module running from a different program

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint

I have a directory structure like:

```
+Root
  +B
    -module_B.py
    -module_A.py
  -mainprogram.py
```

1. From `mainprogram.py` I'm using a function `somefun()` present in `module_B.py`
2. In `module_B.py` I'm using a function `anotherfun()` in `module_A.py`

However when I use the statement **`from module_A import anotherfun()`** in `module_B.py`, and when I run `mainprogram.py` at run time it gives an error **`No module named module_A`** in `module_B.py`.

So I changed `from module_A import anotherfun()` in `module_B.py` to **`from B.module_A import anotherfun()`** and it runs fine only for `Pylint` to give me an error when typing in `Visual Studio Code` which although harmless is annoying.

Comment: do you have empty `__init__.py` in directories?

Comment: yup that was the reason. But now I have changed every `import/from` statement in every python file of my project to include the _'fully qualified name'_ which specifies the exact location of the file with respect to the root directory. **`Pylint`** doesn't show any `Intellisense` errors anymore. Am I doing this right?

Comment: Also, if I try to execute any _'individual'_ file(say for example `module_B.py`) directly from the command line, which here in this case is part of the whole project, it now shows an error regarding the `file` path because of the fully qualified path name in the `from/import` statements. **It is normal no?!? because it is now part of something bigger and not an individual entity in itself right ?!?**

Comment: I ll put it in simple context `folder1 -> folder2 -> file1 -> function1` correct import is `from folder1.folder2.file1 import function1` make sure you have `__init__.py` at root and inside every folder

Answer (score 0):

You should try adding a `__init__.py` file to the root directory to import what you need form the 'B' dir. 
For example your `__init__.py` file should contain;

```
from B.module_B import anotherfun()
```

And then your `mainprogram.py` file can simply include;

```
import anotherfun()
```

This helps to keep everything organized in the long run, if your add more directories, etc.

Comment: I don't think that's the correct answer as errors gets worse. Check the new replies under the question.